# Comparison of Kodaira dimensions in semistable degenerations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi \colon Z\to \Delta$ be a semistable degeneration with a simple normal crossings central fiber $\pi^{-1}(0)$. Here $Z$ is a smooth complex projective variety (or Kähler manifold), $\Delta$ is a small disk around origin in $\mathbb{C}$, generic fibers $X$ of $\pi$ are smooth, and the central fiber is a transverse union of smooth varieties $X_i$ along snc divisors $D_i\subset X_i$

Question: If fibers of $\pi$ are 2-dimensional (or more generally in higher dimensions) and $Z$ is minimal (or similar to exclude blowup components etc.), what is known about the relation between Kodaira dimension of smooth fibers $X$ and the logarithmic Kodaira dimensions of $(X_i,D_i)$?

For example (except for some trivial situations), if $X$ has Kodaira dimension $0$, then $(X_i,D_i)$ have logarithmic Kodaira dimension zero as well. (For basic degenerations with positive genus singular locus, this is even true in the symplectic category by a [result](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701617) of Michael Usher)

Comment: Greetings Mohammad!  I think you need to add some minimality / ampleness condition.  If you take an arbitrary $Z$ over $\Delta$, if you blow up a smooth point of the central fiber, then you produce a new irreducible component -- the exceptional divisor.  With your definition, that pair is $(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{P}^{n-1})$, and this does not have log Kodaira dimension $0$.

Comment: Definitely, I forgot to write that, thats what I meant by trivial situations in that example. Nice to hear from you Jason.